# how can I display flask selected video display

Tags: python, flask

I want to display the selected video using a flask.
I select a video using HTML

```
<input id = "video_re" name = "video_select" accept = "video/*" type = "file"  >
<input type="submit"  value="testing" id="button_click" >
```

and then get the file name

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    f  = request.files['video_select']
    video_name = f.filename

    return video_name
```

and display

```
def video_gray(selected):  
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(selected)
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  
        grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # video grayscale
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', grayFrame)
            grayFrame = buffer.tobytes()

            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + grayFrame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(video_gray(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
html
<img src="{{url_for('video_feed')}}">
```

selected video name is `video_name` how can i how can i this value send to `video_gray(selected)` ?
or another way to display the selected video?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use the global variable, declare the **video_name** as global and you can use it anywhere you like*

or try these, maybe this will help,

Just send the post data directly to the *video_gray* function

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['POST'])
def video_gray():
  f  = request.files['video_select']
  selected = f.filename
  camera = cv2.VideoCapture(selected) ...
```

or you can just call your function in the *test()* function

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['POST'])
def test():
   f  = request.files['video_select']
   video_name = f.filename
   video_gray(video_name)
```

Comment: if i use global variable, what should i do test() function's return?